# After renaming (shift-F6) in PyCharm, how do I access the "Do Refactor" button with a hotkey?

Tags: pycharm

I want to get to the "Do Refactor" button with a hotkey. Apparently it's "D", but hitting that makes me search for "d" instead. Anyone know what to do?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In PyCharm you can press `Alt + d` to do `Do Refactor`.